# Manual line break in listings or listings doesn't work in figure env

Tags: listings

The example illustrates my problem. I have long code rows which should break automatically (see line 1) but some lines I want to break manually (line 2 / 3). How can I do this?

I have played a little bit around and example 1 could be a solution but it doesn't work in figure environments (example2).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
   breakatwhitespace=false,
   breaklines=true,
   escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
   frame=lines,
   numbers=left,
   postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rightarrow\space}},
   showlines=true
}

\begin{document}

Example 1:
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
a = b + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
a = b (*@\\\ensuremath{\rightarrow\space}@*)  + c
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{2cm}
Example 2:
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
a = b + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
a = b (*@\\\ensuremath{\rightarrow\space}@*)  + c
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The culprit is the `\centering` you are issuing inside the `figure`, not the `figure` itself.

Removing it the problem is solved.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}

\lstset{
   breakatwhitespace=false,
   breaklines=true,
   escapeinside={(*@}{@*)},
   frame=lines,
   numbers=left,
   postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rightarrow\space}},
   showlines=true
}

\begin{document}

Example 1:
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
a = b + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
a = b (*@\\\ensuremath{\rightarrow\space}@*)  + c
\end{lstlisting}
\vspace{2cm}
Example 2:
\begin{figure}[h]
\begin{lstlisting}[numbers=left]
a = b + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c + c
a = b (*@\\\ensuremath{\rightarrow\space}@*)  + c
\end{lstlisting}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Arghhh... Thanks, Latex is sometimes so illogical...